# PyMuPDF add bold & italics & underline & stikrethrough text

Tags: python, pdf, pymupdf

I was looking at the PyMuPDF package and it says

[image]

https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/recipes-text.html#how-to-insert-text

However I cannot find documentation on how to do this?

My end goal is being to able text dynamically that can be bold, underline, strikethrough and italic (including a scenario where the text is bold & underline & strikethrough & italic).

Is PyMuPdf able to handle this?  **Edit: Yes you can see answer**

Comment: I am a maintainer of PyMuPDF. Please look at methods `insert_text()`, `insert_textbox()`. As a start. Also note, that underline, highlight and strike-out are no text property, but achieved by annotations. Bold, italic are font-properties, not text properties. Achieve this by changing the font. In addition to all that, you can also start from text styled via HTML and CSS, and PyMuPDF will convert it to PDF, automatically choosing the right fonts. I recommend you visit this [Discord](https://discord.gg/65WQSP4v) channel for help and inspiration.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the recommendations I have updated my code in the question to reflect this. My only remaining issue is that the strikeout and underline is appearing in different colors. How can I resolve this?

Comment: code finally updated :)

Comment: Thank you for your time all issues resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code that is able to bold, underline, italics, and strikethrough:

```
black= (0, 0, 0)

font_name = 'courier'

if bold and italic:
    font_name += '-boldoblique'
elif bold:
    font_name += '-bold'
elif italic:
    font_name += '-oblique'

# Add the text as a textbox
page.insert_textbox(
    rect=page.rect,
    buffer=text,
    fontname=font_name,
    fontsize=12,
    align=0)
    
# Search for the newly added text
rl = page.search_for(text, quads=True)

# add strikeout if applicable
if strikeout:
    annot = page.add_strikeout_annot(rl[0])
    annot.set_colors(stroke=black)
    annot.update() # **Edit** - this line required to update annot.

# add underline if applicable
if underline:
    page.add_underline_annot(rl[0])
    annot.set_colors(stroke=black)
    annot.update() # **Edit** - this line required to update annot.
```